# What is this strange worm-like creature?

Tags: species-identification

[image]
Hi! While I was in my front yard this morning, I happened to look down and see this little guy wiggling thru the grass. He isn't like anything I've seen before.

He is about 2 1/2 inches long. He has a small horn coming out of his back near what appears to be his behind. His belly is a light green color. Also, he starts to flick around when I touch him (To catch him, I scooped him up in a small pot.)

I live in north west Mississippi in the hills near the delta. I am also surrounded by a large forest with all kinds of both pine and normal trees, if it helps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A picture of the underside or a profile would probably be nice if you still have it around. Most likely a caterpillar or another larva. A giveaway that it is an insect larva is if you inspect the legs, you will see that there are 3 pairs of true legs, near the head, and any other leglike things along the rest of the segments of the body aren't really true legs.

Comment: Sorry, but I put it back where it was little while ago!

Comment: Also, it had really stubby legs, if that helps.

Comment: The horn on the last segment is caterpillar-like. "stubby legs" too. Searching for "caterpillar with horn" led me to species of this genus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manduca, but the photos of caterpillars I got didn't look like yours. The colour of yours is not a familiar caterpillar colour for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is some sort of [Cranefly larvae](https://nature.mdc.mo.gov/discover-nature/field-guide/crane-fly-larvae), see here:  I've found these guys both directly in streams and along the banks of rivers, but also underneath rocks far away from major sources of water. There are different types of cranefly larvae, but they all have the same characteristics, (bulbous bodies, worm like, not easily noticeable arms, alien encephilization)

[image]

It may also be deer [fly larvae](https://nature.mdc.mo.gov/discover-nature/field-guide/horse-and-deer-fly-larvae) ( a type of horsefly ) but they typically are more "spiky" on the sides.

[image]